# CSS - How to Affect All Images EXCEPT for One Particular Image

Tags: css, image

How do I set conditions to affect all images within my webpage (via CSS) **except** for one particular image which I have already set the conditions for specifically?

For example:

```
#rightMain img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This affects any images within the `#rightMain` ID.

However,

```
img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

This also affects the image in the `#rightMain` ID in that is skews the overall resolution of the image, causing it to look unnatural.

I would like to know how to affect all images except for the one in `#rightMain` as I have applied specific formatting to this image and do not wish to change it; it must exist in one state, and in one state only, within the `#rightMain` div.

I am aware of declaring a div class/ID to affect child/parent/sibling elements, etc, but I cannot seem to be able to figure this one out.

My main aim is to keep the image within `#rightMain` exactly as it is declared, but to also be able to affect all images - excluding the aforementioned image - throughout the rest of the page/site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting height: 100% with both selectors - I can't see where is the difference that is causing you problems?

the only thing that comes to my mind before you clarify your question, is to have:

```
#rightMain img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /*override height: 100%; */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}


img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - this was not quite what I was looking for as I am using `img{}` to make all images fit to the maximum height set by their container, but I am using `#rightMain{}` to affect a single image and to also put a border on it; this is why I am using two separate declarations.  However, I have resolved the issue now using your suggestion as a guideline. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The priority goes to the more specific CSS rule,
 and in case of the same css rule the priority goes to the last one parsed.

in your case

```
#rightMain img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

is more specific than

```
img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

so the #rightMain img { ... } can rewrite attributes specified into the img { ... } rule.

You can also use the :not() CSS3 selector but is risky because is not supported by all browser, you can read more about it here: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

html:

`<img id="myid" src="somepic.png" />`

css:

```
img#myid {
   /*apply some props to it*/
}
```

Make sure you put this img#myid selector *after* you stated any code that applies to all images.

Comment: img#myid is redundant, #myid is enough as there must be only one tag with a given id.

also it does not have to be after any img {...} selectors as an id selector is more specific than a tag selector

Comment: It's not neccesary, no. However, for clarity it's useful. It's a matter of personal preference ;)